# I don’t want YouTube(JP), I want YouTube(US)

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to change the location YouTube assigned to me?

[image]

I don't want YouTube(JP), I want YouTube(US). Could someone help me on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top right of YouTube, you will see your YouTube icon. Once you press it you should see this...[image]

And then you just press on location and change it to whatever location you want (United States if you want US).

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in your account, simply click on the profile icon in the top left and in the menu there's a item with location that you can change.